# How to Change the Contents ("value") of a Custom Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, custom-attributes

I have the following HTML5 Custom Attribute:

```
<input ... class="my-input" data-counted="N">
```

How do I change its value (from "N" to "Y") in jquery?

Here is what I have and it does not work:

```
$(document).on('change', '.my_input', function() {
    $(this).attr('data-counted').val('Y');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
$(this).attr('data-counted','Y');
```

or

```
$(this).data('counted','Y');
```

Comment: awesome...that did it. I'll accept this as the answer later -- service won't let me for 10 more mins